# stripe bank to bank direct transfers

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

OK, I am a little confused on the best way to setup Stripe for customer to customer direct bank transfer. Here's what I want to do.

I am building a rental platform where a tenant and landlord can enter their bank information (routing and account) and then on a monthly basis transfer money from the tenant to pay the landlord directly (ie, bank to bank transfer) for that months rent.

I think Stripe Connected account makes the most sense to make this happen. But I guess I am not fully understanding the flow, even after reading the docs. Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) to accept payments on behalf of others. In your scenario, you'd create [customers](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) for the tenants and [connected accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_account) for the landlords, then [create charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) to move funds from a tenant to a landlord, with your platform optionally taking a cut out of the transaction.

Since you want the tenant to pay via bank transfer, you'd need to use [ACH](https://stripe.com/docs/ach) rather than cards.

Comment: That worked - Thanks! 

Here's what I did - I created a customer on my Connected Platform and I added a Connected Account (both with bank accounts attached) then from the connected platform I ran:

    `\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    'amount' => 1000,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'customer' => 'cus_9FCdtsYODtW0p8',
    'destination' => 'acct_18vzqgLENUxVxWkk'
  ));
`