# Charging a credit card with stripe connect

Tags: php, stripe-payments, credit-card, stripe-connect

I started working with Stripe and created a web application, where *User A* can purchase an Item from this site, his/her credit card will be charged by Stripe and the money will be transferred to my Stripe Account. Stripe validates the user's credit card and sends a token back, which, in combination with my secret Api Key, will create the charge.

So now I started working with Stripe connect and want to do the same thing except instead of transferring the money to my account, I want *User A* to purchase the item of *User B*, who has also created a Stripe account. So I have all the Information of *User B* (by fetching the data from Stripe's API) and thought I could just use the access_token from *User B* instead of my secret Api Key, and let the credit card token be the same. But in the Stripe docs they use the CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID. So am I mistaken with my approach? And is it even possible to use Stripe Connect the way I am trying to?

Comment: Do you still need an answer?

Comment: Can you look at [this question and its answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629140/stripe-bank-to-bank-direct-transfers) to see if they give you any insight?